# Proof of (forall x, a -> b) /\ (exists x, a) -> (exists x, b)

Tags: logic

I am attempting to prove:
    `(forall x, a -> b) /\ (exists x, a) -> (exists x, b)`.

I know how to prove this given a more forgiving set of axioms and derivation rules, but what I have is a bit restrictive.

My available inference rules include modus-ponens:
    `a, a->b |- b`

and generalization:
    `a(x) |- forall(x, a(x))`

Also include standard substitution rules.

My axioms:
1) Any Tautology in Sentential logic with 3 boolean variables or less.
   (Assume standard definitions for boolean operations: ~, /\, V, ->, <->).
2) `(forall x, a(x)) -> a(t)` (Where t is 'substitutable' for x in a)
3) `forall(x, a -> b) -> ((forall x, a) -> (forall x, b))`
4) `a -> (forall x, a)` (if x is not free in a)
5) `forall(x, a) <--> ~exists(x, ~a)`

Some current theorems I have already derived that may be helpful:
`(forall x, a /\ b) <--> (forall x, a) /\ (forall x, b)`
`(forall x, a) -> (exists x, b)`

My derivation system has no ability to temporarily introduce assumptions that are not proven, as you might expect in a natural deduction system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I found my own solution.  For what it's worth, this problem actually should have been posted to https://math.stackexchange.com/, but what is done is done.  For those of you who may be curious, here is the solution.  Incidentally, the rules are borrowed from Enderton's logical axioms in "A Mathematical Introduction to Logic".  However, the axioms are not entirely identical.

Before proceeding with the theorem, I should introduce a couple other theorems and a meta-theorem I proved with these axioms.  (I will use these in the derivation below).

First: `(a -> b) /\ (b -> c)) -> (a -> c)`  (HypotheticalSyllogism: a tautology).
Second: `exists(x, a) -> ~forall(x, ~a)` (ExistsDefined.  Derived using Rule 5).
Third: `(a->b) -> (~b -> ~a)` (Contrapositive: a tautology).
Next: `alpha, beta |- alpha /\ beta` (ConjunctionIntroduction meta-theorem).
The meta-theorem is observable from the following tautology combined with modus-ponens:
`(a->(b->(a /\ b)))`.
Finally: Any Tautology, no matter how many variables, can be derived using just 3 variables as a time.  However, the length of the proof will in general grow quickly with the number of variables (assuming NP != coNP).  I use this fact in step 15 of the deduction below where I use 5 variables instead of my limit of 3.

Here now is the proof:

1. `~b -> ((a -> b) -> ~ a)`  (Tautology).
2. `forall(x, ~b -> ((a -> b) ->  ~a))`   (from Step 1).
3. `forall(x, ~b -> ((a -> b) -> ~a)) -> (forall(x, ~b) -> (forall(x, (a -> b) -> ~a)))` (Rule 3).
4. `forall(x, ~b) -> forall(x, (a -> b) -> ~a)` (ModusPonens from steps 2 and 3).
5. `forall(x, (a -> b) -> ~a) -> (forall(x, a -> b) -> forall(x, ~a))` (Rule 3).
6. `(forall(x, ~b) -> forall(x, (a -> b) -> ~a)) /\
   (forall(x, (a -> b) -> ~a) -> (forall(x, a -> b) -> forall(x, ~a))) ->
   (forall(x, ~b) -> (forall(x, a -> b) -> forall(x, ~a)))` (from HypotheticalSyllogism).
7. `(forall(x, ~b) -> forall(x, (a -> b) -> ~a)) /\ (forall(x, (a -> b) -> ~a) ->
   (forall(x, a -> b) -> forall(x, ~a)))` (ConjunctionIntroduction steps 4 and 5).
8. `forall(x, ~b) -> (forall(x, a -> b) -> forall(x, ~a))` (ModusPonens steps 6 and 7).
9. `(forall(x, ~b) -> (forall(x, a -> b) -> forall(x, ~a))) -> (~(forall(x, a -> b) -> forall(x, ~a)) -> ~forall(x, ~b))` (Contrapositive).
10. `~(forall(x, a -> b) -> forall(x, ~a)) -> ~forall(x, ~b)` (ModusPonens steps 8 and 9).
11. `exists(x, b) <-> ~forall(x, ~b)` (ExistsDefined).
12. `exists(x, a) <-> ~forall(x, ~a)` (ExistsDefined).
13. `(exists(x, a) <-> ~forall(x, ~a)) /\ (exists(x, b) <-> ~forall(x, ~b))` (ConjunctionIntroduction steps 11 and 12).
14. `(~(forall(x, a -> b) -> forall(x, ~a)) -> ~forall(x, ~b)) /\ (exists(x, a) <-> ~forall(x, ~a)) /\ (exists(x, b) <-> ~ forall(x, ~b))` (ConjunctionIntroduction steps 10, 13).
15. `(~(a -> b) -> ~c) /\ (e <-> ~b) /\ (d <-> ~c) -> (a /\ e -> d)` (Tautology Meta-Theorem).
16. `(~(forall(x, a -> b) -> forall(x, ~a)) -> ~forall(x, ~b)) /\ (exists(x, a) <-> ~forall(x, ~a))
     /\ (exists(x, b) <-> ~forall(x, ~b)) -> (forall(x, a -> b) /\ exists(x, a) -> exists(x, b))` (from Step 15).
17. `forall(x, a -> b) /\ exists(x, a) -> exists(x, b)`  (ModusPonens steps 14, 16).